# For a set to be ordered, do we need to define an equivalence relation on the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), one condition for the total order is that $\forall a,b \in A (a \le b \;\wedge\;b\le a \rightarrow a=b)$. Does this mean that we must have some equivalence relation defined on A for it to be ordered in the first place? i.e. Can a set be ordered without having some $=\;\subseteq A \times A$ defined on it?

Comment: How do you distinguish the elements of a set if you cannot even tell when two of them are equal or not?

Comment: The "=" is *not* an additional equivalence relation. It is the actual *equality*.

Comment: Note that every set comes with at least the trivial equivalence relation -- each equivalence class is a singleton.